# Programmatic constraints cut the bottom of my label off

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uilabel, nslayoutconstraint

I have a Nib file with a root `UITableViewCell` and child `UILabel` that I anchor at run time using programmatic constraints

```
        lblAccountItemTitle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        lblAccountItemTitle.topAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
        lblAccountItemTitle.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
        lblAccountItemTitle.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgAccountItemLeft.trailingAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
        lblAccountItemTitle.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -32).isActive = true
        lblAccountItemTitle.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

[image]

Also, I've noticed that the shorter I make my bottom anchor, the less clipped the text is

How can I get rid of the clipping while still maintaining the equal 16 vertical padding?

Comment: try removing the top and bottom constraint of the label as its already constraint on the Y center of the view. (or change it to centerY of your image. ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was programmatically pinning the label to the cell and not to the `Content View`

**self.topAnchor**

should've been

**self.contentView.topAnchor**

Answer (score 0):

change the **both** image and label bottom anchor from **equalTo** to **lessThanOrEqualTo**

```
lblAccountItemTitle.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
```

Comment: If I change the font size, then it will not be consistent with the rest of the tableview items. I need the text to be the exact size I have it and have a 16 padding on top and bottom, and the cell should resize it's height  accordingly.

Comment: then remove the centerYAnchor and try

Comment: The text still clips

Comment: i think your image and the this label is bottom of the tabelview cell. change the both items bottom anchor from equalTo --> lessThanOrEqualTo

Comment: the image is just centered vertically. I'm not sure that the constraints are at fault. It seems like the cell is not automatically resizing itself.

Comment: can you add the cell automatic resizing codes that you used

Comment: First remove the heightForRowAt function if you used it, then add `yourTable.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension`
        
and `yourTable.estimatedRowHeight = 100`. after register the UITableViewCell

Comment: clipping still happens